# Why is 12/8 used sometimes for songs in 4/4 in sheet music?

Tags: sheet-music

I understand that 12/8 can be counted as 4/4 time where each beat gets a triplet but I don't understand why some songs that seem apt for 12/8 still get written out in 4/4. What are the criteria for which gets chosen?

Comment: I reckon, sometimes, there's no good answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some songs with a triplet/shuffle in 4/4 are written in 12/8 for ease of notation/reading but sometimes the notation in 12/8 will not allow for all the notes to be written this way so 4/4 must be used and all the triplets notated individually.

Answer (score 3):

And why is 4/4 sometimes used for music apparently in 12/8?

Here's a classic example.  Written in 4/4 (well, 2/2 'cut time' actually, but let that go for now) rather than 12/8.  Beethoven has chosen the time signature that suits the melody with its dotted 8th - 16th rhythms rather than the accompaniment with its (LOTS of) 3-groups.

[image]

and here are two approaches to notating a shuffle (NOT swing - just for once that 'metric modulation' 8th = triplet notation is accurate) tune.

(Publishers usually go with the 12/8 option for 'Blueberry Hill, perhaps someone thought that too 'hard' for guitarists?):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Key sig. or time sig? (Para.2).

Comment: Thanks but why did Beethoven choose to write it like that?

Comment: Like I said, he had to pick triplets for the accompaniment or duplets for the melody.  In some pieces the convention is that dotted rhythms over three-groups are played as triplets.  Not, I think, here.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely ease of writing, and ease of reading. In 4/4 it needs to be stated that each crotchet is to be treated as 3 quaver triplets, which then can give the piece a swing feel, instead of a straight eight feel.  Swing is roughly (sometimes exactly!) the first two quavers tied, followed by the third. I call it the 'Humpty Dumpty' rhythm.

So, unless the piece has specifically lots of separate quavers, amounting to 12/8, it's written in 4/4 with a note at the top.

Comment: Oh dear.  No, Swing is NOT 12/8 or triplets.  If you want swing, write 'Swing'.  If you want 12/8 write 12/8, or triplets, or maybe 'Shuffle'.  I don't know wht educators are so frightened of just asking for 'Swing'.  It's been part of our musical vocabulary for 100 years now.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - We're going to agree to differ here. But often 'swing' or 'shuffle' is notated at the top with two quavers = a triplet with the first two tied. Funny that.

Comment: Which is correct for shuffle, not for swing.  Yes, it's done for swing.  I'm suggesting it shouldn't be.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - could be the start of another question...

Comment: Ok for ease of notating I can understand but this song (see link at the end) is clearly a shuffle and would be much easier notated in 12/8 but it is in 4/4 with all those triplet quavers and I can't understand why  https://ibb.co/iq7d8y

Comment: Clearly 4 lots of triplets per bar, so yes, easier written and read were it in 12/8. Funny it explains at the top, then later there's the triplet 'slur' marks. No need? Toss of a coin, I expect. Bit like some march tunes *could* be 2/4 with triplets, *or* 6/8. I sometimes have to decide which is the better way to write, and it's sometimes a toss up.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have studied this song a little bit more and please look at this part https://ibb.co/hqP3Fo , I think those 16th notes would be a problem written in 12/8 wouldn't they? I am speaking about the words "dreams and they are". COuld that be why 4/4 was chosen?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a formula for this.  It is up to the composer to write in such a way that makes sense to them and, ideally, would be easy for a performer to read.  The choice will likely depend on the tempo of the piece.  To quote Paulson & Cheyette:

"Composers do not always write in the meters best adapted to the speed or tempo of their compositions, but rely on the performer's sense of rhythm and interpretation."

Comment: No but there is logic and in my example ibb.co/iq7d8y nobody could explain why the piece is written in 4/4 when everyone will agree by first looking at it that it would be better in 12/8. Only a small section of the song has a part that would not be able to be written in 12/8 and that is why it is written in 4/4.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  Your original post offered no example and I think my answer exactly addresses your comment, that when it seems obvious that a song would be in one time signature it turns out to be in an other.  Music theory is not a set of unbreakable, unambiguous laws like math or physics.  These are guidelines that have developed over 100s or 1000s of years.

Comment: my response to Tims answer I provided an example of a song that could be written in 12/8 but the writer decided to use 4/4 and tediously write out each set of triplets. There must be a reason they didn't use 12/8. The reason is for one small part of the song that would not be able to be written in 12/8.

Comment: I don't know how to address that comment.  My answer is based on experience and standard music education.  Why someone does or doesn't do something that makes sense to others is a matter of psychology :-).  If you are looking for someone to "explain" someone else's decision this may not be possible (or worth the effort).

Comment: You can change signature in a song.  So a follow up question might be why didn't the composer/arranger do that so the music look nice all the way through?

Comment: I have stacks of sheetmusic books and I have never seen that happen. Not saying you are wrong but just not in the style of music that I am writing/learning/playing. Might make a good new question? I don't agree that asking why something is written the way it is has to do with psychology really because that would make hundreds of questions on this site void, including my own.

Comment: But that is true

Comment: I'm not saying that asking such questions is invalid but you have to be willing to accept that there is no absolute answer to some of them.  Music isn't as cut and dry as other disciplines and personal choice and ethnic habits are a big part of the evolution of music theory and smn.